# Is there a way to save cordova app instance on OnPause Event or something similar to SavedInstanceState in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

We develop an cordova app with ionicV1 framework. Our app have a camera integration to take picture and send picture to a server. We use the cordova camera plugin.

And recently on some new ANDROID (android only) devices like OnePlus6T, when we leave the app to go to the camera activity (system activity camera), during this time spent on the camera the application is killed by the system. And so when the camera activity give their result, the app restart and so we are not anymore on the good app page...

So, they have some ways to fix this issue :

- Handle onPause and onResume with save app instance (like savedInstanceState on Android)
- Find a way to avoid the app to be killed (but with some search is not recommended to do this ... use of background mode cordova plugin is deprecated)
- I see some threads about android launchMode we are currently on singleTop... Maybe is a track to explore

So we would like than when we leave the app for the camera activity no matter if the app is killed or not by the system, arrive to the good app page to display the image take before.

Anyone already had this kind of problem ?

What is the best way to follow ?

Thank you,